# Fair price: receive sum of the last decreasing sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value, problem-solving, game-theory

This is a Jane Street Interview question.

> What is the fair price of a game in which you shuffle nine cards labeled 1 through 9 then keep choosing whether to open the next card or stop, given that you will receive the sum of the last decreasing sequence?

So far, I have solved for the expected value of having $2$ cards which is $\frac12 \times 3$ and the expected value of having $3$ cards, which is $2 \times \frac23$. My question is, how do we even determine the expected value of the decreasing sequence in the first place. I cannot find anything online about this. After solving that, I believe we can simply compare expected values to determine optimal stopping.

Comment: The rules aren't clear. If you stop at a point, you get the last card you saw along with it's priors so long as they increase (reading them backwards)?  That is, if you draw $12398$ and stop, you get a payout of $17=9+8$?   To be clear, it would be dumb to stop then, right?  Since the next draw is sure to be lower than $8$ and hence would increase your payout.

Comment: If that's right, then a crude strategy is to wait for the $9$ since you know the next one (if there is a next one) will add to your total.  That isn't optimal, as $876543219$ should obviously be stopped at the $1$ (actually, prior to that $1$).  But it might give you a quick handle on the strategy.

Comment: That is the only strategy I could come up with. I am trying to calculate the expected value of this process, but I am unable to.

Comment: Are you counting individual numbers as a sequence? For example, if I draw $123$ and stop, do I receive \$3? If so, then the expected value for the $2$ card version should be $5/2$, since if you draw $21$ yields \$3 and $12$ yields \$2.

Comment: If one is allowed to program, then the exercise is easy and the answer is $2749727/181440\approx 15.1550209435626$ unless I have made a programming error. However, I do not see how to immediately guess that it is between $15$ and $16$ with just pen and paper.

Comment: How did you program this?

Comment: @GaryLiang You receive the last sequence. So if you draw 4132, you get 3+1=4 and not 4+1=5.

Comment: @RichardD you can program it by counting all possibilities.

Comment: @RichardD can you give some example on the results of draws?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Just give examples.

Comment: If you draw 4132, I would have assumed you get 3+2=5, since you receive the sum of the last decreasing sequence?

Comment: It not too hard to see that the strategy "wait for the largest thing, then take cards only if there is no risk to you" gives an expected value around 13.5, fwiw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to take a dynamic programming approach (which I think should be similar to fedja's answer). Let $A(n,\ell,S)$ be the expected reward when the current sum is $n$, the last number drawn is $\ell$ and the set of remaining numbers is $S$. We're looking for $A(0,10,\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\})$ (here $\ell$ can be any number greater than $9$).

For each state $A(n,\ell,S)$, we consider either stopping or drawing:

- If we stop, the expected reward is $n$.
- If we draw another card, we need to consider every card that's left. For each card $i$ in $S$, if $i \le n$, it continues the decreasing sequence, and the expected reward is $A(n+i, S-\{i\})$. If $i > n$, it breaks the sequence, and the expected reward is $A(i, i, S-\{i\})$.

Here is a Python implementation of this logic:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def A(current_sum, last_number, remaining_numbers):
    # If there are no numbers left, the expected reward is the current sum
    if not remaining_numbers:
        return current_sum
    
    # Compute expected value of drawing another number
    EV_draw = sum(
        A(current_sum + i if i <= last_number else i, i, remaining_numbers - {i}) 
        for i in remaining_numbers) / len(remaining_numbers)
    
    # The optimal strategy is to stop if current_sum >= EV_draw, and draw if current_sum < EV_draw
    return max(current_sum, EV_draw)

# Initialise with current_sum = 0, last_number = 10 (greater than any card), and all numbers remaining
print(A(0, 10, frozenset(range(1, 10))))
```

This gives an expected value of $2749727/181440 \approx 15.15502094356261$.

If anyone can work out the formula, we also have the following answers starting with $2$ cards: $5/2, 25/6, 143/24, 463/60, 6853/720, 57229/5040, 66713/5040, 2749727/181440$. (It looks like there could be a $n!$ in the denominator).

Comment: The only OEIS hit for 5, 25, 143 is https://oeis.org/A285382

(Surely $n!$ is the denominator: that's the size of the sample space, and each achieved value is an integer.)

Comment: Elegant implementation. The result agrees with fedja's answer

Answer (score 2):

(**migrated from comments**)

If one is allowed to program, then the exercise is easy and the answer is $$\frac{2749727}{181440}≈15.1550209435626$$
unless I have made a programming error. However, I do not see how to immediately guess that it is between $15$ and $16$ with just pen and paper.

---

*How did you program this?*

Here is a simple recursive code I used. It is by no means efficient, but with numbers so small pretty much anything you can write would execute reasonably fast. The language is Asymptote.

```
real f(int[] a, int lst, int sm)
{
if(a.length==0) return sm;
real s=0;
for(int k=0;k<a.length;++k)
{
int newlst=a[k];
int newsm=(newlst<lst? sm+newlst:newlst);
int[] b; 
for(int kk=0;kk<a.length;++kk)
if(kk!=k) b[b.length]=a[kk];
s+=f(b,newlst,newsm);
}
return max(sm,s/a.length);
}

int[] a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
real u=f(a,10,0);
write(u, u*factorial(a.length), factorial(a.length));

pause();
```